# JavaScript/JQuery splitting a form into a 2-part/page form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a Django developer and am tasked with splitting up a form into a 2 page/part form. Basically first part is `Account` registration, and the second part is `Business` registration.

Im not too great with JavaScript, but I almost have a solution, but needs some tweaking.

basically the HTML is split up into 2 divs like this..

```
<div class="tabs">
    Account form is put in here
<div class="tabs">
    Business form in this div
```

My buttons are set up like this for Previous/Next...

```
<button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
<button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
```

MY JavaScript function looks like this.

```
function showTab(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
}



function nextPrev(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        document.getElementById("SignupForm").submit();
        return false;
    }
    showTab(currentTab);
}
```

Now my issue is when I first bring up the registration page, it displays both divs "tabs" with ALL fields included, `Account` and `Business`.

When I hit `Next` at the bottom of the page it shows only the second div business form (Which is great), and then when I hit `Previous` it shows only the first div account form (Which is great).

Now my only problem is when the registration page is originally brought up for the first time, it is showing both of the divs named "tabs". Is there a quick easy tweak that can be done to my original function to just bring up that first div "tab" on first page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline styles by setting the style directly on the second tab, like so:

```
<div class="tabs">
    Account form is put in here
</div>
<div class="tabs" style="display: none;">
    Business form in this div
</div>
```

some docs
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
[link2](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)

Comment: Ahh just missing some CSS!? Thanks a bunch! My front end skills need some work!